# Generic functions and Subclasses. Can anyone explain this compile error?

Tags: swift, generics, compiler-errors

Can anyone explain to me why the last case in this example is a compile error?

```
class A{}
class B: A{}

protocol Finder{
    func find< T: A>(_ f: (T)->Bool)  -> T?
}

class FinderImpl : Finder{
    func find<T : A>(_ f: (T) -> Bool)   -> T? {
        //In the real code I use T to find the instance. I.e. CoreData
        return nil
    }
}

let finder = FinderImpl()

//OK 
let optionalB : B? =  finder.find{_ in true}
let a : A =  finder.find{_ in true}!
let b : B =  finder.find{(b: B) in true}!

//Compile Error
let b2 : B =  finder.find{_ in true}!
```

**let a.** The compiler uses `(A) -> Bool.` as the closure type. Then the return type is A.

**let b.** This compiles because the closure has explicit information: `(B)->Bool`

**let optionalB.** I wonder why this case works, here the closure has no information either. The difference is the `! operator`

**The Error:** In the last case the compiler is failing to infer the type of the closure passed to func find. It is suggesting me to cast `as! B` because it thinks that the closure type is `(A)->Bool`. It is not using the reference type of b2 B.

**Important:** I cannot cast `as! B` because I need the find function to actually use the type B. If I cast `as! B`, the function will use type A and get the wrong instance. The code would compile but the results would be wrong.

**If I remove the `T:A` restriction, there is no compile error.**

This looks like a compiler bug to me. I think the compiler should use the type of b2 to know that the closure is `(B)->Bool` and then the result type of find. The `T:A` restriction and the lack of type information in the closure is causing it to fail.

Am I missing something here? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Because Swift cannot infer the return type in the last example.

In your generic function, you declared that `T` must be `A` or a subclass of `A`:

```
func find<T : A>(_ f: (T) -> Bool) -> T? {
    return nil
}
```

Swift can infer what `T` actually is when you specify the type in the closure. That's why this worked:

```
finder.find{(b: B) in true}!
                ^ now T == B
```

Here, you did not provide any type information so the only thing the compiler relied on is the declaration of the generic function, which says `T : A`:

```
finder.find{ _ in true}! // this return A
             ^ what type is this? The compiler doesn't have any extra
               information so it must be A according to the declaration
```

You can get it to compiler by making an explicit cast:

```
let b2 : B =  finder.find{ _ in true}! as! B
```

Or provide the type information:

```
let b3 : B =  finder.find{ (_: B) in true}!
```

*(This is to get it to compile only. The code will obviously crash at run time because you are force-unwrapping a nil value)*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I understand your points, I think I mentioned that in the question too. What I see as a problem is that in let b2 : B, I am actually specifying the type information. T = B. I don't see why it would be necessary to explicitly state (B)->Bool too. Take the optionalB for example, there I am not specifying the closure type, but it works. That's why I think this could be a compiler bug. Any thoughts?